# Visual Studio 2017 RC Cordova Simulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017

Debugging in a local browser with the new VS2017 RC simulator I'm getting the XHR_PROXY issue, previously I could disable the proxy in the Ripple settings  but where are these settings in the new Simulator?

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are adding a way to disable this in tools -> options, but it won't be available for another few RC releases. Thank you for providing this feedback!

(Disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)

Comment: That's awesome thanks for taking me feedback on-board :)

Comment: Please please tell me this made it into the release? I need the setting now

Comment: Yes this should be in vs 2017 rtw

Comment: I think I found It - Tools, Options, Tools for Apache Cordova, Enable XHR Proxying [x]

Comment: And it fixed the issue like magic, thanks for the hard work on this module